# Java installed via SDKMAN does not work with Bash Terminal

Tags: java, bash, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, sdkman

I'm a Mac user and I've installed Java 11 via SDKMAN. I have no problem running and compiling java code in both VSCode and IntelliJ using zsh terminal, but when I use bash (my preference), I get the following error message.

"The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java."

I have the following configuration in my bash_profile

```
# make .bash_profile same as .bashrc
if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ]; then source "${HOME}/.bashrc" fi export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman" [[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Is there any other configuration I need to get java to work using bash?

One more note is that this issue is only present in the IDE terminals that I'm using. I can use the Macbook terminal with bash and have no problems. I've also made sure that both IDEs have the appropriate JDK settings/point to the SDKMan "current" version of Java.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I've configured Java in the IDEs that I'm using, but this doesn't help the issue. Also, to be clear, java works, and I can compile code using the zsh terminal. I just get this error when using the bash terminal in these IDEs

Comment: Just to be sure we’re clear, zsh from the IDEs works, bash from the IDEs doesn’t?

Comment: @randy Yes, exactly

Comment: I tried with sdkman, only used file `.bash_profile` and no `.bashrc` used:
```
#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```
java and javac works well in bash shell and IDEA's terminal, any other info might be helpful, such as a screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried configuring the Java runtime in vscode? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-runtime-for-projects

Comment: I think some details on how you're even accomplishing this in IntelliJ would help, too... I've changed "Shell path" to `/bin/bash` and opened a new Terminal, but `echo $SHELL` will still report `/bin/zsh`. Maybe that's from my personal config outside of IJ, but details as to how you've configured things would probably help us toward a solution.
That aside, why bash? I'm not sure I see a reason for this preference....

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I don't know if this might be the issue with config, but you're missing the ';' before fi (also check if export in same line as if dont need seperator or new line)

Before:

```
if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ]; then source "${HOME}/.bashrc" fi
```

After:

```
if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ]; then source "${HOME}/.bashrc"; fi
```

I have extra questions:

1. Is the path JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) really the directory where java is located? Why you need this variable? (if you need it, please put it to new line). I use ubuntu, so it could be diffrent but my machine print **/home/[username]/.sdkman/candidates/java/current** when **echo $JAVA_HOME**
2. Are you sure the fragment with sdk is at the end of the file?

Remember that after updating .bashrc you need to reset temrinal.

Comment: To answer #1, Mac is similar. It’s /Users/<username>/.sdkman/candidates/java/current. And #2, it is if the OP hasn’t made any changes. It also doesn’t matter _that_ much as Docker will want something similar. Finally, terminal restart in an IDE is a bit meh. `source ~/.bash_profile` should work, too, assuming that’s the right file. I don’t know why OP wants to use bash over zsh and it seems like a really good way to get rc file confusion…